Query and Transposing Google Sheets Data
The spreadsheet is currently in this Google Sheets format.

I am trying to pull out the data from sheet1 table to sheet2  ...transposed as follows in the 2nd image. 


Original data will grow...a new row every period
So Query output needs to grow ... a new column every period

I have not been able to accomplish this and keep things dynamic.

Consider providing input and expected output as plain text table in the question. Click here to create a table easily, which are easy to copy/paste.  Avoid sharing links like spreadsheets, which make the question useless for others or images, which are hard to copy. Also, note that your email address can also be accessed by the public, if you share Google files.

You may use the following script as basis for yours:
function segregateData() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Input");
  var shOut = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output");
  var dataCol1 = sh.getRange(1, 5, 1, 5).getValues();
  var dataColTrans = dataCol1.map((x) => x.map(y => [y])).flat(Infinity);
  dataColTrans.unshift("Items");
  var data = sh.getRange(2, 3, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 7).getValues();
  var data1 = data.map((x) => x.length >= 2 ? [x[0] + " (" + x[1] + ")"].concat(x.slice(2)) : x);
  var data2 = data1[0].map((x, i) => data1.map(y => y[i]));
  var dataOut = []
  for (var i = 0; i < data2[0].length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < data2.length; j++) {
      dataOut.push([dataColTrans[j], data2[j][i]])
    }
    j = 0;
    dataOut.push(["", ""]); //spacing
    dataOut.push(["", ""]); //spacing
  }
  shOut.getRange(1, 1, dataOut.length, dataOut[0].length).setValues(dataOut);
}

Test Setup:
This script works given the following setup:

The Google Sheet has two sheets (Input and Output)



The Input looks like this:


You may edit the line:
shOut.getRange(1, 1, dataOut.length, dataOut[0].length).setValues(dataOut);

to adjust the placement of your output.
Output
The expected output should look like this:

References:

map()
push()
unshift()
slice()


Please feel free to comment if you have other questions.

Bueatiful code!  To adjust the number of items  from 5 to 56  what line of code would need adjusting?

In line 7, change 7 to 58 (inside the .getRange() function). So it's like number of items +2

Yes... I had to adjust line 4 as well... worked nicely ...Thank you so much
